# How to compare right and left side of a string in SQL

Tags: sql-server

The idea is that if the first name and the last name are the same, the column indicator should put a 'fail' and if not, should enter 'pass'

```
SELECT TOP 1000
name,
case when CHARINDEX(' ',=name)<>0 
and LEFT(TRIM(=name),CHARINDEX(' ',=name)-1)=RIGHT(TRIM(=name),CHARINDEX(' ',c=name)+1) then 'fail' 
else 'pass' end AS indicator
FROM Table
```

I have an entry in the column name that is N/A N/A and I think it should fail with the case I wrote but is giving me a 'pass' I am not sure what could be the problem here

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just write something simple like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_NAME 
(
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50), 
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_NAME
SELECT 'FIRST', 'FIRST'
SELECT 'LAST', 'FIRST'

SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN  PN.FIRSTNAME = PN.LASTNAME THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN  PN.FIRSTNAME <> PN.LASTNAME THEN 'PASS'
        END AS NAME_PASS_FAIL   
FROM #TEMP_NAME PN
```

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIojB.png)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, splitting like I usually do it. Although names may not have only one space in them.

```
with tbl(name) as (
select 'Darth Vader' union all
select 'N/A N/A' union all
select 'joe mama'
)
SELECT name,
case 
  when SUBSTRING(name,0,CHARINDEX(' ',name)) = SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1,LEN(name)) then  'fail' 
  else 
    'pass' 
  end AS indicator
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Thank you, I had not realized that the RIGHT function counts the indexes from right to left, it does work with substring!